# invalid procurement or argument

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an extensive excel pivot table macro that creates 6 pivot tables. Whenever I try to run the macro I receive an error (5), invalid procurement or argument. I have looked through various forums and cannot find a fix for this error. The error resides somewhere in lines 3-6. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.I am not skilled in the VBA language.

```
Range("A5").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "All Open Tool Records 05-22-20!R1C1:R4750C27", Version:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Department")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use variables to capture the various objects in your process - that makes the whole thing easier to manage:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets.Add() 'assuming this is where the pivot table goes....

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:= "All Open Tool Records 05-22-20!R1C1:R4750C27", _
            Version:= xlPivotTableVersion10)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A3"), _
           TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10)

With pt.PivotFields("Department")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: Tim,Thank you. I will try adding variables and report back with my results.